# Best way to create a Bit/Byte array arithmetics class

Tags: arrays, math, byte, bit, biginteger

I'm currently working with really large numbers and I want to do simple calculations with them, but I have problems. Even c# BigInteger timeouts when I'm creating the numbers from a byte array.

The bytearrays are really really large, like up to several MB each.

So I thought that I could create a "byte array calculator" that takes 2 arrays and adds / subtracts them.

```
bit[] result = BitArrCalculator.Add(arrA, arrB)
// arrA is 1001 (9)
// arrB is 11 (3)
// then result should be 1100 (12)
```

Because I have extremely large numbers I can't convert them to ints and back again. Atleast not in c#. If there are other languages out there that can do this, I could change language but I would like to have a solution that could handle arbitrary array sizes.

This feels like there should exist a solution / library / framework out there, but I haven't found it.

So my question:
What is the best way to work with bits/bytes arrays and do addition/subtraction on them and are there any tools/libraries out there?

Comment: Sounds like a fun problem to solve from scratch (in any language).

Answer (score 0):

Untested.

```
byte[] Add( byte[] one, byte[] two )
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[ Math.Max( one.Length, two.Length ) ];
    int carry = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < one.Length && i < two.length; ++i )
    {
        int total = (int)one[i] + two[i] + carry;
        if( total > 255 )
        {
            carry = total - 255;
            total = total - carry;
        }
        ret[i] = (byte) total;
    }

    // at most one of these for loops will execute

    for( int j = i; j < one.Length; ++j )
    {
        int total = carry + one[j];
        if( total > 255 )
        {
            carry = total - 255;
            total = total - carry;
        }
        ret[j] = (byte) total;
    }

    for( int j = i; j < two.Length; ++j )
    {
        int total = carry + two[j];
        if( total > 255 )
        {
            carry = total - 255;
            total = total - carry;
        }
        ret[j] = (byte) total;
    }

    if( carry > 0 ) { /* have to add another byte to the array */ }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write my own class that can do addition and subraction with two given bit arrays. For me in my project it made more sense to work with bits than bytes. And the logic to do addition and subtraction is really simple with bits.